# Can "where" be used to connect two phrases that one is part of the other?

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions

According to the [Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/where), "where" can be used as a conjunction:

> *conjunction*
>
> You use where after certain words, especially verbs and adjectives, **to introduce a clause in which you mention a situation, a stage in something, or an aspect of something.**

I think I can see where my case fits in the definition, but not sure as it doesn't explicit it. I may also find "where" fits in my sentence below because it just sounds natural.

My sentence:

> With tons of clothes **where** some do matter.

*It is not a complete sentence*

The same sentence but is rewritten for explanation purposes:

> With tons of clothes, and some of them (do) matter.

My question is: if "where" appeared to be correct, then it would be connecting a thing that is part of another more general thing. Is this true?

---

**P.S.**

The sentence that precedes:

> With tons of clothes **where** some do matter.

Is

> You are a girl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use "where" to introduce a clause.

Example:

> I love to visit cities where there are museums.

This means that you love to visit cities, but a *condition* of that is that the city must have a museum.

Your example sentence doesn't seem like it needs a "where" clause - "*You are a girl with tons of clothes, and some of them (do) matter*".

It seems to me that you are either trying to say:

> You are a girl with tons of clothes, but only some of them matter (to you).

(Meaning that, in *your* opinion, the girl is holding onto clothes that are not important to her)

Or, alternatively:

> You are a girl with tons of clothes, *only some of which* matter to you.

Neither of these really contain a "condition", merely an observation or opinion of your own that some of her clothes matter to her, and some of them do not. The fact that she only cares about some of them doesn't change the fact that she owns "tons", so it is not a conditional statement.

An example of a *conditional* statement would be:

> You only own clothes that matter to you.

This is because her ownership of the clothes is *conditional* on them mattering to her.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually want to avoid stating whether explicitly or implicitly that some of her clothes don't matter, so I may go with "and" at the end.